# Поделитесь ссылками на зарубежные сайты с креативным дизайном страничек

Tags: css

Нужна ссылка на пример сайта с неформальным, креативным решением, желательно зарубежного происхождения.

Comment: Друзья программисты! не скупитесь, поделитесь находками, может у кого завалялась пара тройка приятных трофеев. Предложения типа "оказывается есть гугл" не принимаются!

Comment: [Дизайн и интерфейсы](http://technovzor.com/category/designandinterface/). Особенно рубрика "Сайты которые вдохновляют"

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку. Контент интересный

Answer (score 1):

Вот:
[tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/)

Answer (score 1):

1. http://www.nikebetterworld.com/
2. http://benthebodyguard.com/
3. http://www.webleeddesign.com/ (жать на shop cверху)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению на вопрос откликнулись лишь два участника форума, досадно, надеялся на  большую активность. Спасибо **Spectre**, спасибо **andy** ресурсы "стоящие"!
Возможно кому-нибудь будут полезны и мои находки:

- [http://bombiadesign.com/portfolio/](http://bombiadesign.com/portfolio)
- http://brokedesign.com/
- http://good-wallpapers.com

Comment: http://www.jimcarrey.com/
Вот ещё посмотрите, но это уже шедевр конечно))

Comment: я бы не стал бросаться такими громкими словами

Comment: Спасибо andy. К сожалению на шедевр не тянет.